# how to deploy nuxt 3 on Plesk or IIS

Tags: node.js, vue.js, deployment, nuxt.js, plesk

how can i deploy nuxt 3 on Plesk or IIs on windows server.
what config needs to do this.
i appreciate anybody to answer me

i had transfer the .output file in httpdoc on my domain and below config on     node js application
node js version : 18
Document root : httpdocs
Application Mode : production
Application Root : httpdocs
Application Startup File : entery.js

```
entery.js:    
import('./.output/server/index.mjs')
```

when i see my domain in browser, result is this     "import('./.output/server/index.mjs')"

Comment: Did you checked some questions for Nuxt2 on this website? May help.

Comment: I have deployed nuxt 2 on Plesk without any problem but the solution for deploying nuxt 2 and deploying nuxt 3 differ from each other

Comment: the file has to be named entry.js, not entery.js

Comment: i have do this but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem is solved
I deploy Nuxt3 on Plesk successfully via the below comment on GitHub by the author of Nuxt Poya Parsa
https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/9789#issuecomment-1361454980

Comment: Please accept your own answer when you can.